# failed to run the app from iOS simulator from Android Studio after upgrade to Flutter to 2.5.0

Tags: flutter, android-studio, ios-simulator, flutter-ios, flutter-ios-build

I can't run my app on iOS simulator. I have this error after upgrading to Flutter 2.5.0 from Flutter 2.2.3

I can't run the Flutter app from Android Studio. **but If open the project from the Xcode then the app will run without issue in iOS simulator.**

here is the error/warning message

```
 ld: building for iOS Simulator, but linking in object file built for iOS, file '/Users/xxxxxxx/Documents/main_app/ios/Pods/GoogleMaps/Base/Frameworks/GoogleMapsBase.framework/GoogleMapsBase' for architecture arm64
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    note: Using new build system
    note: Building targets in parallel
    note: Planning build
    note: Constructing build description
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'FMDB' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'libwebp' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'TOCropViewController-TOCropViewControllerBundle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Reachability' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'Mantle' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'AppAuth' from project 'Pods')
    warning: The iOS Simulator deployment target 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' is set to 8.0, but the range of supported deployment target versions is 9.0 to 14.2.99. (in target 'GoogleSignIn' from project 'Pods')
```

I have tried several solutions from SO, but have no luck. what I have tried so far

1. flutter clean
2. delete podfile.lock. following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64474526/9101876)
3. delete the app in simulator

here is my Flutter doctor

> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.0, on macOS 11.2.1 20D74 darwin-x64,
> locale en-ID)
> [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
> (Android SDK version 31.0.0)
> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS [✓]
> Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3) [✓]
> VS Code (version 1.60.0) [✓] Connected device (3 available)

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      if config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'].to_f < 9.0
        config.build_settings.delete 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can change 9.0 to the deployment target version of your project.